# Call another script inside PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to call a variable script name. I need it as a  variable so that i can replace it with a parameter. This code below somehow dose not work.

```
DECLARE
    mypath CHAR(30);
BEGIN
    mypath := '&1'; 
    @mypath
END;
```

Any help please!

Comment: You aren't going to be able to run a shell script from within PL/SQL; at least not without some serious coding skills and system privileges.  What is it that you hope to accomplish?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run SCRIPT from PL/SQL Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830427/run-script-from-pl-sql-block)

Comment: Stilgar is right. You can, but you shouldn't do this. Tell us what you want to do..

Comment: i would like to call a sql script inside pl/sql. I am able to do this by embedding the filename and path like this @my_script.sql but my problem is the file name is not static meaning it can be changed. So that is why i need it as a variable.

Comment: How do you run your script? If using Toad you can place variables like this: `:myvar` and Toad will ask you for an input.

Comment: i am using sqlcl. 3 files actually, 1 is batch, 2 is the main.sql and the query.sql. The batch will call the main.sql and from main.sql call the query.sql which needs to be a variable because the filename is not always query.sql. So the batch goes like this: sql.exe user/pwd@mydb @main.sql  %1. The %1 is the query.sql which is the variable filename with path.

Answer (score 0):

*PL/SQL* scripts is a subset of *Sqlplus* scripts. In other words you cannot run `PROMPT hello` from inside of *PL/SQL* block.

Although there's a way to run pure *PL/SQL* script stored in a file from *PL/SQL* block, I don't recommend it, because with a little thinking you're able to find more clear solution.

Anyway here's that dirty hack:

```
my/lovely/little_script_1.sql

BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('hello from little_script_1');
END;
--------------------    

my/lovely/little_script_2.sql

BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('hello from little_script_2');
END;
--------------------

@main.sql

DECLARE
  v_file_contents varchar2(32767) := q'[
@&1
]';
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_file_contents
END;
/
--------------------

@run.sql

set serveroutput on

@main.sql my/lovely/little_script_1.sql
@main.sql my/lovely/little_script_2.sql    
--------------------

sqlplus user/pass@DB @run.sql
```

Notice, that `little_script*` files are pure `PL/SQL`, particularly they lack the `/` symbol in the end.

It's important to understand that construct `@file_name.sql` inlines file contents into current script if only `@` is the first non-space character in the line regardless of where this construct is placed. Also it takes place even inside PL/SQL - it's an undocumented feature (or a bug which never will be fixed).

So an implicit result of substitution `@main.sql my/lovely/little_script_1.sql` will be:

```
DECLARE
  v_file_contents varchar2(32767) := q'[
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('hello from little_script_1');
END;
]';
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_file_contents
END;
```

Since file contents are just being inlined as is, mind handling quotes correctly.
For instance, if `little_script_1.sql` contains anywhere a string terminator symbols `]'`, then `main.sql` will face a syntactic error - try it yourself.

Comment: Thank you! I am surprise by the dirty hack hehe. Anyway I got a different solution much easier. Let me show you below:

Answer (score 0):

echo on
set lines 200 pages 999 trims on echo on feed on timing on time on

spool '&1'

@'&2'

spool off
spool '&1' APPEND

DECLARE

myoption CHAR(1);

BEGIN

myoption := '&Do_you_want_to_commit_y_n';

if myoption = 'y' thenQ
    commit;

else
    rollback;

end if;

END;
/

spool off
set echo off
exit;

Comment: the @'&2' is the variable parameter sql file. It is an insert DML. The proceeding codes are PL/SQL block which will ask the user either to commit or rollback.