# How from one script call another scripts

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm working in PL/SQL and I have a problem. I need from one script(name of script is Start.sql) call another 7 scripts and they need to work.
Is there anyone who can help me?
Thank you..

Comment: A script can call another script using [@otherscript.sql](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/at-sign.html#GUID-60FF1F84-55CE-4B6C-8513-9FA84C17CD42) or [@@otherscript.sql](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/double-at-sign.html#GUID-AD1F392F-8D07-4424-8376-0FE3A721E3B1). What isn't working?

Comment: i never work that so idk is it working or not haha, but i try now you example and it say Unable to open file: "Create.sql"

Comment: You mean, `start.sql` contains a line like `@Create.sql`, and the error is there's no such script? That sounds pretty self-explanatory to me.

Comment: yeah,  for me it is also incomprehensible. I never do anything like this

Comment: Please include details of your test case in the question, so we can try it out and see what's going wrong.

Comment: @mohdatif [notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63505849/3744182) that [Run SCRIPT from PL/SQL Block](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8830427/3744182) is related, or duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Are they propably functions or procedures?

Normally you call them Database.Package.Procedure (Parameters)
so for example

```
myvariable INTEGER;
myvariable := MyDatabase.MyPackage.MyProcedure(TheUsedParam);
```

Note: Name of database / package don't need to get called if they are in same package / database

Comment: I have 7 tasks to do, i have job test and i need make full app and every task i need to save in script(1.task is to create tables and they need to be in one script, another task is make 2 function and procedure and save it in package and then need to save them in another script...) and when boss come he want start.sql script to have and from this script to call all app.. sory for english if i make some grammary mistakes

Comment: Seems like what you are looking for is how to build an SQL*Plus script. In that case refer to [Oracle User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/using-scripts-in-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-DFCF7A00-B15A-4B10-8493-46D2248BCC2A). If needed find that guide for your Oracle Version.

Comment: i found a problem, idk how but i don't even have a sql*plus on my comp so that's why @script.sql didn't work.. Thank you all for help!